# Custom page numbers (other than Roman or Arabic)?

Tags: page-numbering

For example, how do I label the very first page as "Cover"?

Or, label the first 5 pages as "Cover-1", "Cover-2", ... "Cover-5"?

Comment: What should happen after the first five pages? Does the numbering restart a 1, or does it continue with 6?

Comment: @Mico: Yea it restarts at one (either Roman i or Arabic 1) or whatever I want.

Comment: Could you enlighten us as to what "whatever I want" might entail? My crystal ball is showing only dense fog today, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The `fancyhdr` package provides almost limitless possibilities for changing the header and footer material on a page. The following code shows how to make the first page "number" be just a string label, followed by five pages numbered consecutively "Cover-i", "Cover-ii", ... , "Cover-v". Switching to LaTeX's "plain" page numbering system is also possible.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy} % switch to "fancy" page style
\fancyhead{} % no material in header
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\cfoot{First Page} % <-- just a string, no numbers

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2] % no page "number", just the label "First Page"

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{roman} % set page number to 0, lowercase-roman numbering 
\cfoot{Cover--\thepage}
\lipsum[1-25] % "Cover--i", "Cover--ii", etc

\clearpage
\pagestyle{plain} % switch to "plain" page style
\pagenumbering{Alph} % uppercase-alphabetic "numbering"
\lipsum[1-12] % next 3 pages are numbered "A" thru "C"

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have seen your precedent comment. Is there dense fog :-)?+1

Comment: @Sebastiano - The OP may, or may not, want alpha-numbered pages at some point... :-) Really hard to tell.